# find two or more similar characters in nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

In T-SQL, how would you check if a string contains two or more similar characters?

I have column contains mobile numbers of nvarchar which could be "5512111445","6612888445" or hidden numbers like "5512zzz44x"

I have a search pattern entered by the user which could be "xx12yyy4zx" and i would like to return all the matched  numbers to this pattern where x,y,z representing any number, but if it's repeated it will representing the same number. the previous pattern for example should return all the listed numbers above.

xx are similar numbers like 55 or 66.. whereas xy are different numbers like 45 or 67..

How can this be done?

Comment: Lookup T-SQL regular expressions. http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/ or http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html I'm not familiar with their use but I'm pretty confident they would work here.

Comment: How does xx12yyy4yz match 6612888445, when y corresponds to both an 8 and a 4?

Comment: you're right john, i already updated the question, it is xx12yyy4zx for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pivot each character in the mask and number into columns, and then group on mask alone followed by mask + number. In this method 5512111445 and 6612888445 do not match mask xx12yyy4yz because the y in mask does not map to a unique digit. However, mobile numbers 5512111415 and 6612888485 do match mask xx12yyy4yz, as does mobile number 5512zzz44x.

```
--declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='5512111445'; --no match because @mask y maps to different values
--declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='6612888445'; --no match because @mask y maps to different values
--declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='5512111415'; --no match because @mask x should not equal @mask z
--declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='6612888485'; --matches
--declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='8812888485'; --no match because @mask x should not equal @mask y
--declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='5512zzz44x'; --matches because z and x are both hidden and different
--declare @mask varchar(10)='xx12yyy4yz';

declare @mobileNums varchar(10)='3211zyy'; -- no match because @mask y <> @mask z, but @mobileNums y = y
declare @mask varchar(10)='3211yxz';

declare @t table(n char, m char);
declare @i int=1;

while @i<=LEN(@mobileNums) begin
    insert into @t values (SUBSTRING(@mobileNums,@i,1), SUBSTRING(@mask,@i,1));
    set @i+=1;
end

if exists(
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Group by m
    select
    m, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by m
    except
    select
    m, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by m,n

    union

    select
    m, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=1
    group by m
    except
    select
    m, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=1
    group by m,n

    union

    select
    m, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=1 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by m
    except
    select
    m, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=1 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by m,n

    union

    select
    m, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=1 and ISNUMERIC(m)=1
    group by m
    except
    select
    m, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=1 and ISNUMERIC(m)=1
    group by m,n

    union

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Group by n

    -- Add a rule that no numeric @mobileNums digit can correspond to more than one alpha @mask character
    select
    n, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=1 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by n
    except
    select
    n, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=1 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by m,n 

    union

    -- For GROUP BY n, include the three remaining combinations of ISNUMERIC(n) and ISNUMERIC(m)
    select
    n, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by n
    except
    select
    n, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=0
    group by m,n    

    union

    select
    n, c=count(m)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=1
    group by n
    except
    select
    n, c=count(m+n)
    from @t
    where ISNUMERIC(n)=0 and ISNUMERIC(m)=1
    group by m,n 

)
select patMatch='False'
else 
select patMatch='True';
```

**EDIT** - Add a rule that no numeric @mobileNums digit can correspond to more than one alpha @mask character

**EDIT** - For `GROUP BY n`, include the three remaining combinations of ISNUMERIC(n) and ISNUMERIC(m)

**EDIT** - removing the eighth `UNION`

Comment: Thank you so much john, quite brilliant solution, but it's dealing with xy as simillar numbers, if the mask have xy it must be different numbers, any thoughts to get rid of this issue as well?

Comment: @Ala, yw. I added a union at the bottom where I group by numeric digits in `@mobileNums` where the corresponding `@mask` digits are characters. This should enforce the rule that x and y must correspond to different respective digits.

Comment: firstly thanks for update, you are really A Master of SQL,
 
Your code returns patMatch='True' if for example, the mask is '3211yxz' and the number is'3211zyy', Here we have yy corresponds the same number but xz corresponds different, Any suggestion to solve this problem please?

Comment: Yes, to the `GROUP BY n` queries, I simply added the three remaining combinations of ISNUMERIC(n) and ISNUMERIC(m). Re-ran for all the test examples in the comment block. +1 great question! A bit of a deep dive here.

Comment: Thank you once again for you contribution, something goes wrong after your last update it's returning Match for 'x9' and 'x8' !
I just removed the last 'except', and it worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to code the whole thing because it will be tedious but I think this can get you started.

1. Convert the search pattern into a like pattern, replacing all alphabetical chars with underscores. This reduces the # of rows you have to search through, but still can leave you with a lot to sift through.
2. For each char in the pattern, filter the rows that match the pattern. Example for "5512zzz44x":

   1. Start with 'z':

      - "5512zzz44x" -> "5512zzz44_"
      - Either loop through results filtering out rows with each pass, or generate dynamic SQL and then execute after the whole thing is created:
      - "5512zzz44_" -> `... mobile_num like '551200044_' or mobile_num like '551211144_' ... or mobile_num_like '551299944_'`
   2. Next char: 'x':

      - "5512zzz44x" -> "5512___44x"
      - (follow pattern from 2.1 above)

The idea is to progressively filter out the results until you are left with only the #'s that match the original pattern.

There are probably much more efficient ways to do this. If deploying CLR's is an option, it might be a better idea to do this with CLR & Regular Expressions.

Comment: Another option instead of using a bunch of `like`, at step 2.1 and 2.2, etc, select all results into a temp table with columns: (1) concat of all chars at 'z' positions in all the pre-filtered mobile_num's, and (2) 1st char of the value in col (1). Then filter out all rows in this temp table where all the values aren't the same, using a `where col_1 like '%[^'+col_2+']%'`. Continue filtering until you've done this for all the "variables" in the search pattern.

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own answer rather than updating the answer.

Comment: The comment holds an alternate solution. It was faster and clearer to keep the two ideas separate. Is there something wrong with commenting on my own answer like this?

Comment: Thank you so much Giscard your solution in the previous comment is logical, but i can't mark it as answer that's why 'Blam' asked you to update the answer or to add another post, here. however i am also working on john's post below but xy must be different numbers, thank you very much any way.